# Detecting when TCP connection fails to open or is terminated

Tags: sockets, haskell, tcp

I am reading and writing to TCP socket via a duplex handle h.

In the client:

```
sock <- socket (addrFamily addr) (addrSocketType addr) (addrProtocol addr)
connect sock $ addrAddress addr
h <- getSocketHandle conn
```

In the server:

```
sock <- socket (addrFamily addr) (addrSocketType addr) (addrProtocol addr)
setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
withFdSocket sock setCloseOnExecIfNeeded
bind sock $ addrAddress addr
listen sock 1024
forever $ do
  (conn, _) <- accept sock
  h <- getSocketHandle conn
  forkFinally (server h) (const $ hClose h)
```

where:

```
getSocketHandle :: Socket -> IO Handle
getSocketHandle conn = do
  h <- socketToHandle conn ReadWriteMode
  hSetBinaryMode h True
  hSetNewlineMode h NewlineMode {inputNL = CRLF, outputNL = CRLF}
  hSetBuffering h LineBuffering
  return h
```

When both the client and the server are available, it all works fine, but when the TCP connection terminates, e.g. because the client or the server exit, nothing happens - `hGetLine`/`hPutStrLn` just block the thread.

How can I make them throw exception?

Similarly, if the client fails to connect (e.g. because of the server not responding), `connect` also just blocks.

I suspect I should somehow set the timeouts on the socket, but experimenting with socket options didn't change much - I tried SO_LINGER, SO_KEEPALIVE, SO_USER_TIMEOUT doesn't seem to be supported by the system (it blocks when I try to get it), SO_RCVTIMEO / SO_SNDTIMEO don't seem to be supported by [Network.Socket](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.2.1/docs/Network-Socket.html#g:7) - at least that's what the docs say...

For `connect`/`hPutStrLn` I could use `timeout` from `System.Timeout` (it seems a hack, but it will work), but for `hGetLine`/`hGet` it won't work - it can just wait for user input, so it should only throw exception when the connection terminates.

I should probably just read the network programming - I was hoping to figure it out quickly... Any help is really appreciated.

EDIT: It seems like I should be using lower level `send`/`sendAll` and `recv`, do buffering and cutting to lines in my code (or read byte by byte - probably it would be buffered anyway as set in `listen`) and treat 0 length returns by `recv` as disconnection. Isn't there a way to make it work via handle with higher level functions?

Comment: Do you have a minimal example that illustrates the problem?  I can't duplicate either problem with your code -- for me, when one end hangs up, the other's `hGetLine` gets an EOF exception; when there's no server available, the client's `connect` call gets a `Connection refused` exception.

Comment: Thank you again - it was my mistake. Trying to reproduce with a simpler case it did work as you described - the issue was due to not handling the exceptions correctly in some cases - see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of [K. A. Buhr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7203016/k-a-buhr), I figured out that the issue was not related to handle/socket, and the exceptions are indeed thrown correctly.

Minimal client/server setup that is working: https://gist.github.com/epoberezkin/d6063c0d8f6e95d9e606652565113413

It's based on the example in Network.Socket package, but handles multiple resolved addresses and uses handles to read/write socket.

The real issue was due to incorrectly handling exceptions in some cases, specifically instead of something like:

```
race (send h) (receive h) `finally` disconnected
```

I did

```
race (send h) (receive h) >> disconnected
```